# Hide Pause Duration in Item Workflow History

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have a pause duration of 5 minutes to wait for the default 5min timer job to update a metadata in an approval workflow. Is there a way to hide all the pauses from logging in the Workflow History?

Answer (score 0):

You can develop a custom workflow activity that does pause for 5 minutes without logging.
Have a look at [this site](http://msmvps.com/blogs/sundar_narasiman/archive/2010/12/26/develop-custom-workflow-activity-for-sharepoint-2010-workflow.aspx) to get started.

Comment: Thanks stiangodo, but do you think there is a solution without having to touch visual studios? I havn't started VS yet.

Comment: As far as I know there are no solution for this using SharePoint Designer only.